# Divisibility of a polynomial evaluated at 1's

Tags: combinatorics, number-theory, polynomials

Let $n, l, p$ be positive integers, $l\geq 2$, and $p<n$. Define the polynomial
\begin{eqnarray}
P_{n, l, p}(x_1, x_2, \cdots, x_{2n+1})=l\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(\sum_{\substack{0\leq k_r\leq l-1\\k_1+\cdots+k_{2n+1}=lk-p}}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\cdots x_{2n+1}^{k_{2n+1}}-\sum_{\substack{0\leq k_r\leq l-1\\k_1+\cdots+k_{2n+1}=lk+p-2n-1}}x_1^{k_1}x_2^{k_2}\cdots x_{2n+1}^{k_{2n+1}}\right)
\end{eqnarray}
Show that $2^{n+1}$ divides $P_{n, l, p}(1, 1, \cdots, 1)$.

The case $l=2$ is easy. In this case 
\begin{eqnarray}
P_{n, 2, p}(1, 1, \cdots, 1)=2\sum_{k=1}^n(-1)^k\left(\binom{2n+1}{2k-p}-\binom{2n+1}{2k+p-2n-1}\right)=\pm 2^{n+1}
\end{eqnarray}
How should one approach the general case?

Comment: This does not seem to hold for odd $l$? For example $P(2,3,1)=3( -(15-0)+(51-15))=63$.